# Htaccess rewrite domain to a new domain with the appending path based on the parameter given

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

To clarify, I want to redirect:

```
domain.page.co.uk/path/?lang=de
```

to

```
de.page.co.uk/path/
```

where path will change according to the page I am on.

I want to keep the path of my own domain without the appending parameter at the end but based on my parameter, change the new domain accordingly. So that I can add more rewrite rules for different languages, i.e. lang=fr.

I have tried a few ways but none of them were successful. I am not familiar with htaccess rewrite rule syntaxes. Here are what I have tried based on what I could find online:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/d]+).page.co.uk/?$ ^?lang=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/?lang=de$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://de.page.co.uk/%1 [R=302,NC]

RewriteRule ^de.(.*)/?$  ^(.*)\?lang=de  [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want something like:

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.page.co.uk
RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} lang=(de|fr|it)       [NC]
RewriteRule  .* http://%1.page.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

For an explanation see: [URL Aliasing, Redirection, Rewriting and Reverse Proxying using Apache HTTPD](http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/4043/URL-Aliasing-Redirection-Rewriting-and-Reverse-Proxying-using-Apache-HTTPD.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your code but it doesn't redirect/rewrite when there is an additional path e.g. domain.page.co.uk/path/?lang=de. It works with no path. Also, in the rewrite rule, is it possible to remove the ?lang=de from the new URL?

Comment: To remove ALL cgi parameters from the new URL simply add a **"?"** to the end of the target URL eg. **http://%1.page.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI}?**

Comment: For some reason, the cgi parameter is still showing in the new URL. Do you have any idea why this is the case/any other settings that may be overriding the rule? It is a WordPress site.